# How to force control to fire leave event in winforms using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pasting text in textbox1.text and I need textbox1 should fire its leave event by itself.

For now I am using this following code. but i will appreciate if anyone can suggest me an elegant or better way:-

```
private void event()
{
  textbox1.Text = SearchedText;
  textbox1.Focus(); 
  textbox2.Focus();
}
```

First I am pasting text, then setting up Focus on the control, then set up focus again on second control. It is firing leave event of textbox1, but any thing better?

Answer (score 4):

Just call the code directly, no need to wait for an event:

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        mumble();
    }
    private void someEvent() {
        textBox1.Text = SearchedText;
        mumble();
    }
    void mumble() {
        // etc...
    }
```

Just calling textBox1_Leave(this, EventArgs.Empty) works fine too.

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the `TextChanged` or `Validated` events instead of the `Leave` event.

Answer (score 0):

To FORCE Leave, Validating and so on Events, no matter what, I've found ONE working solution.

First i tried:

```
      ProcessTabStop(true); 
      ProcessTabStop(false);
```

instead of:

```
      textbox1.Focus(); 
      textbox2.Focus();
```

Problem with the TextBox 1 and 2 Focus() is that its only Active Component that needs Leave, Validating and so on fired, not other Controls, and besides, what if the form is dynamic, you as a programmer not necessarily have any idea what Control you are trying to Leave, that's why i changed Control.Focus() method to ProcessTabStop method above. The problem is then, if only ONE Control has TabStop true, there is no control to go to and back from. So Events are NOT Fired.

Next problem is that i not necessarily Close the Form with the mouse so Focus doesn't change, I use a Key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to Accept the Form, and then Leave, validating and so on are NOT fired, when i Send Form Close, as Form Close registers weather there are changes or not. But Values are set in Leave on TextBoxes, so I had to find a solution that worked no matter what i did to it. I almost gave up, actually i had a problem report all filled out, when I thought, what if i set ActiveControl to Null and then to the Control it came from. It worked, but had som "Flicker" due to color change on Parent Panel depending on Active or Inactive.

The "Workaround" that works in all cases is:

```
        Control Old = ActiveControl;
        // ActiveControl.SuspendLayout();
        // ActiveControl.FindForm().SuspendLayout();
        ActiveControl = null;
        ActiveControl = Old;
        // ActiveControl.FindForm().ResumeLayout();
        // ActiveControl.ResumeLayout();
```

That seems to fire Leave, Validating and so on Events, no matter number of Form Controls and TabStopped Controls. You MAY need to SuspendLayout on either ActiveControl, or Form. My Control (Parent Panel) changes color when Active/Inactive, if I do not Suspend Layout on Form, parent panel gets an unwanted "flicker" effect.

Looking at the solution, it is very obvious, now I've found it, but took me half a day to try different things that solved one or another problem, but not all.

I know this a VERY old thread, but one of very few articles I've found on the subject of Forcing Leave Event to be Fired.